# Android L, ripple effect not working properly in Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, rippledrawable

I'm using `sdk 21` and added `buttons` to a `gridview`. However, somehow, only the first button is showing ripple effect when clicked and others not showing...

Edit: I found if I didn't add onClick listener to the buttons, the ripple effect is showing, but after I add the listener, only the first one is showing ripple effect...

Edit: Well, after further investigation, I found the effect is gone after I call setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()

I got the resourceId by following:

```
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.hashtag_button);
        mSelectedResourceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.hashtag_button_selected_image, R.drawable.star_selected);
        mUnselectedResourceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.hashtag_button_unselected_image, R.drawable.star_unselected);
        a.recycle();
```

I change image by following method:

```
public void setFavorite(boolean isFavorite) {
    mIsFavorite = isFavorite;
    if (mIsFavorite) { //Favorite
        this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, mSelectedResourceId, 0);
    } else { //Not Favorite
        this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, mUnselectedResourceId, 0);
    }
}
```

So this caused only first button has ripple effect... Not sure how to solve this...

Anyone has same issue?

Thanks